# Which artifact for org.springframework.mail?

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, jakarta-mail

I'd like to use spring support for sending mails. My project is built with maven-2 and I use spring-core 2.5.5  I tried to look in maven central repo for artifact to include in my pom.xml, and the only one I found is [spring support](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-support). The problem is that the highest version in repo is 2.0.8 and it depends on spring-core v. 2.0.8. Should I add it and exclude from its dependencies spring-core, spring-aop and so on, or should I look for another artifact (but which one will do?) or use another repo? Which is the proper maven-2 artifact for org.springframework.mail and where can I find it?

Comment: I got here for Spring Boot, so leaving a comment which might help someone in the future: Include this Maven Dependency:   `<dependency>  
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
  </dependency>`

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The mail stuff is found, rather bizarrely, in the [context-support artifact](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support).

Comment: spring framework is ridiculous.....where in [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mail.html) does it ever mention the need for "context-support".  Hey Spring....only 1/2 the world has wasted their life in Maven....

Comment: ... and all org.springframework.mail source assets are hosted in the [main *SpringSource/spring-framework* repository](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-context-support/src/main/java/org/springframework/mail).

Comment: Any idea how to find this? Is there a reverse lookup table or something I can use?

Answer (score 35):

```
 <!-- ########### SPRING-CONTEXT-SUPPORT ############ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

For using `MailSender` and `SimpleMailMessage` through Spring you can use these imports in your code:

```
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
```

And add their jars in your project.

Otherwise if you are using maven then you have to make these imports in your source and then add dependencies :

1. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-support/2.0.6
2. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support/3.2.0.RELEASE

You will get the mail support from both of them.